# how to check if mongoose (MongoDb) is installed or not

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I installed mongoose using

```
sudo npm install -g mongoose
```

Please advice on how I can check to see if its installed properly. I am using Mac

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To check if `mongoose` module is installed simply find the version by

```
npm list mongoose
```

To check globally

```
npm list -g  mongoose
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked and it returned the version, How do i start my mongo db server?

Comment: probably late to the party but you can start the server through the terminal, using mongod.exe and mongo.exe respectively( in windows, of course)

Comment: So whenever I try to install mongoose, It says mongoose is installed, but as soon as I open a new instance of cmd, the query comes back up empty again... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16):

Mongoose is a npm module. Mongodb may or may not be installed.

To check whether mongodb is installed:

```
which mongo
```

To install mongodb locally:

```
brew install mongodb
```

Then follow the post-installation instructions.

```
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mongodb/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
```

Test your connection to mongodb.

```
mongosh
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MongoLab, to connect to database type: mongo
If you are running Mongo locally, start the Mongo daemon:
In the terminal type: mongod
If that doesnt run try: sudo mongod
Once mongoDB is running open another terminal window and type: mongo
In the same window type: show dbs
To work with a database in the list named myDB, for example type : use myDB

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to check whether mongoose is install in your ubuntu/debian.

a) check locally( means into your project directory within **node_modules**)

For local - **npm list mongoose**

b) check globally( means in your OS within node_modules ).

For global check- **npm list -g  mongoose**

It will show you the version of mongoose, if it already installed. If not then this will show this-

**/home//.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/lib
└── (empty)
npm ERR! code 1**

To install mongoose in ubuntu/debian, run this command in terminal - `npm install --save mongoose`

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you used Homebrew you can check like:

```
mongod --version
mongos --version
mongosh --version
```

and for start(on Apple M1 chip) mongodb manually:

```
mongod --config /opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf --fork
mongosh
```

and for show the databases:

```
show dbs
```

Answer (score -1):

use npm list mongoose
if mongoose is not installed you will get this respose
`-- (empty)